# Activate script on return from sleep mode

Tags: suspend

I use this to monitor my temperatures.

Is there a way for it to run after my computer returns from being in sleep mode (or suspend mode)?

```
Cpu_LogFile="/home/andy/bin/CPU_Fan_Info.txt"

date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S" >> $Cpu_LogFile
sensors -f | grep "temp4" >> $Cpu_LogFile
sensors -f | grep "fan1" >>  $Cpu_LogFile
```

I read the info here.

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/pm-action.8.html

I have this in /etc/pm/sleep.d/, but it does not run when computer returns from a sleep state.

```
#!/bin/bash

case "$1" in
suspend|hibernate)

    ;;
resume|thaw)
    /bin/bash /home/andy/bin/CPU_FAN_INFO.sh
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: Was it originally started before suspend?

Comment: I have it in my startup programs.

Comment: Read `man pm-action`, part of the `pm-utils` package. It explains which directories full of scripts get run on Hibernate/Suspend/Wake/Resume.

Comment: This works, but may not be the best way. echo xb | sudo -S pm-suspend
/bin/bash /home/andy/bin/CPU_FAN_INFO.sh